# Android Eclipse plugin missing options menu to edit XML's

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have looked everywhere for the answer to this question, but cannot find anything on it. Is there anyone that can help me with this predicament? Thank you.

P.S. - I apologize if this question does not belong here, if it does not I will remove it.

Comment: can u post the screen shot of it.

Comment: http://imgur.com/5vc7U.jpg

The menu where I can choose the options for the various things on the screen is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the source, at the bottom of your screenshot, just above the "Console" you see "Layout" & "main.xml", clicking on main.xml will bring you to the source code. If you want the property grid to modify the values of the selected object in the layout,

- Click Window Menu
- Show View -> Other (ALT+SHIFT+Q,Q)
- Expand General Folder
- Select Properties
- Click OK

Answer (score 0):

You mean edit the manifest or layout XML directly? Open the file and click on the "Source" tab at the bottom of the editor window.

Comment: In the WYSIWYG editor when you place like a button, then at the bottom of the screen there is usually a place where you can select various options for that button is missing. I've looked for the source tab or anything that can bring up the Source tab but I have been unable to find it.